# read child nodes xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xmldocument, xmlnode

Here is my xml which i am trying to read.

```
<VacancyList xmlns="urn:abc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" generated="2016-04-20T11:42:47" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abc.in/dtd/vacancy-list.xsd">
  <Vacancy id="1619993" date_start="2016-04-15" date_end="2016-04-22" reference_number="">
     <Versions>
       <Version language="nb">
         <Title>Marketing Specialist</Title>
         <TitleHeading/>
         <Location>CXCXC</Location>
         <Engagement/>
         <DailyHours/>
         <Region>
            <County id="11">sds</County>
            <County id="1">zxzx</County>
            </Country>
         </Region>
         <Categories>
           <Item type="position-type" id="3909">sER</Item>
           <Item type="duration" id="contract">ss</Item>
           <Item type="extent" id="fulltime">sd</Item>
           <Item type="operating-time" id="day">s</Item>
         </Categories>
       </Version>
     </Versions>

 </Vacancy>

</VacancyList>
```

I want to read node location so wrote below code

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        xd.Load("https://abc.in/list.xml");
        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xd.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("msbld", "urn:abc");

        XmlNodeList nodelist = xd.SelectNodes("//msbld:VacancyList", ns);



        if (nodelist != null)
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
            {
                XmlNode nodelist1 = node.SelectSingleNode("Vacancy");
                if (nodelist1 != null)
                    foreach (XmlNode node1 in nodelist1)
                    {
                       var k = node1.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Location").Value;

                    }
            }
```

But i dont get anything in variable "node1". How to fix this?

Also is there any better solution for this?

**Update1**

i modified code but i only get node Title. cant get others inside Version node like Location.

```
if (nodelist != null)
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
            {
                XmlNode nodelist1 = node.SelectSingleNode("//msbld:Vacancy/msbld:Versions",ns);
                if (nodelist1 != null) { 
                    XmlNode nodelist2 = nodelist1.SelectSingleNode("//msbld:Version", ns);
                    foreach (XmlNode node3Node in nodelist2)
                    {
                        var k = node3Node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Location").Value;
                    }


                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xmlns="urn:abc"` is a *default namespace*. Notice that descendant elements without prefix inherits ancestor's default namespace implicitly. You need to use the same prefix that references default namespace URI for acessing `Vacancy` and `Location` as well :

```
XmlNode nodelist1 = node.SelectSingleNode("msbld:Vacancy", ns);
```

---

Your updated code introduces an entirely different problem; `/` at the beginning of a path expression will always reference document element, unless you explicitly set the context to current active context by using `.` before `/`, for example :

```
XmlNode nodelist1 = node.SelectSingleNode(".//msbld:Vacancy/msbld:Versions",ns);
```

Comment: i cant use node.SelectSingleNode("msbld:Vacancy/Versions/Version", ns); to get Location node?

Comment: @Happy you need to use the prefix in your XPath for all unprefixed elements : `node.SelectSingleNode("msbld:Vacancy/msbld:Versions/msbld:Version", ns);` . And regarding your question update, see my updated answer.

Comment: I still get error at this line var k = node3Node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Location").Value; after i used your new solution. I get error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: so how i get value of element Location

Comment: @Happy this way : `var k = node3Node.SelectSingleNode("msbld:Location", ns).InnerText;`

Comment: Sorry this code only reads 1 record for Title and location.. it doesnt loop on all records.. Sorry for unmarking answer

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the `Location` element then you can do it like this:

```
var doc = XElement.Load("path/to/file");
var location = doc.Descendants
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Location"));
```