# logic to add datarow to datatable

Tags: c#, xml, gridview

Currently i am reading xml which has many child nodes and need to bind elements of child nodes to gridview. So i am looping through nodes and add datarows. But i have issue in logic. I create datarow when i loop through 1 node. In that node there are 2 elements. so it first loops on first element and i bind that element to row. In same loop i say add dt.Rows.Add(dtrow) . So it add 1 row with one element. It again loops and adds second element to completely new row. This is wrong. I want to add 2 elements in same row. How can i fix this?

```
foreach (XmlNode vers in g)
{
    foreach (XmlNode vr in vers)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode a in vr)
        {
            dtrow = dt.NewRow();
            if (a.Name == "Title")
            {
                dtrow["Title"] = a.InnerText.Trim();    
            }
            if (a.Name == "Location")
            {    
                dtrow["Location"] = a.InnerText.Trim();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dtrow); // this causes issue.               
        }        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing nested loop like that, you can loop only through elements, say `<e>`, that corresponds to a row in your `DataTable` i.e the number of `<e>` would be equal to the number of rows inserted to the table. In every iteration collect all information from child elements of current `<e>`, possibly using `SelectSingleNode()`.

For example, assuming `vers` contains elements that correspond to the `DataTable`'s rows, you can do something like this :

```
foreach (XmlNode vr in vers)
{
    dtrow = dt.NewRow();
    dtrow["Title"] = vr.SelectSingleNode("Title").InnerText.Trim();
    dtrow["Location"] = vr.SelectSingleNode("Location").InnerText.Trim();
    dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);
}
```

<sub>* Don't forget to use the prefix and namespace manager, if the XML behind this question is the same as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745223/read-child-nodes-xml)</sub>

---

Responding to your comment about doing this without namespace manager; ignoring namespaces is possible, but is also generally frowned upon, because namespaces are there for a reason.

You can either use XPath's `local-name()` function to match element without considering its namespace, for example :

```
dtrow["Title"] = vr.SelectSingleNode("*[local-name()='Title']")
                   .InnerText
                   .Trim();
```

or using LINQ to match by `XmlNode`'s `Name` property, similar to what you did initially :

```
dtrow["Title"] = vr.ChildNodes
                   .Cast<XmlNode>()
                   .First(o => o.Name == "Title")
                   .InnerText
                   .Trim();
```

Comment: i get error on line vr.SelectSingleNode("Title").InnerText.Trim()  as Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I am using another approach. Not same in previous question as you mentioned. I didnt wanted to use namespace manager.

Comment: @Happy I mentioned about whether *the XML* is the same, not *the approach*. So, the XML is still the same right? (i.e the XML still has default namespace in it)

Comment: Yes it still has namespace and its same xml

Comment: @Happy answer updated to provide alternative which doesn't use namespace manager

Comment: This fails . This only retrieves one element. this is xml https://santander.easycruit.com/intranet/intranett/export/xml/vacancy/list.xml

Comment: @Happy Not sure how it considered fail. I assume `vr` references `Version` element in the XML, and each `Version` can only contains one `Title`. So the code intentionally fetches only one `Title` element from current `Version`, and the outer loop make this done for every `Version` element. What's the problem with all that?

Comment: But then i can only fetch one record for Title... Thatswhy i had one more loop which you removed.. There are multiple records for element Title. As you can see in xml url i gave there are 3 records for Title

Comment: There are 4 `<Title>` in your XML, each located in `<Version>` parent, right? If my assumption is correct (if not please clarify), the `foreach (XmlNode vr in vers)` loops through the `<Version>` elements, right? In this case you should get all the title, one at every `foreach` iteration. If this isn't the case please update your question with an [MCVE] codes

Comment: you are corret with assumptions.. foreach(xmlnode vr in vers) loops through version node

Comment: @Happy Post your attempted codes that returns only one `Title`, I don't get what you're complaining about..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110086/discussion-between-har07-and-happy).

Comment: i have one more doubt in that.. can you come on chat please?

Comment: sorry i was at lunch. can you come again. i have very little query